# Converting strings to uppercase and using char at method

Tags: java

i need to convert the first letter of a string of names to uppercase and using the charat method but not sure how to use the char at method

Comment: You need to do something related to a Java String, so you might want to start with the documentation (JavaDoc) for `String`

Comment: real helpfull i taged it as homework im not looking for u to make the code for me just help using the char at method

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure on how `charAt()` could be really useful in your case, but you can try this :

```
String s = "yourString";
char firstCharInUpperCase = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0));
String yourNewString = new StringBuilder(s).setCharAt(0, firstCharInUpperCase).toString();
```

---

**Resources :**

- [Javadoc - String.charAt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))
- [Javadoc - Character.toUpperCase()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase(char))
- [Javadoc - StringBuilder.setCharAt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt(int,%20char))

Comment: i have a string of names that is lowercase and need to convert the first letter to uppercase so i was trying to use the charat to get the first letter and convert it to uppercase

Answer (score 1):

```
string s="hello";
s = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1);
The output will be: Hello
```

**Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0))** is used to convert the 0th character of the string to uppercase.

**s.substring(1)** is the string from index 1 to the end.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I have this utility when uppercasing person names :

```
public static String generateFullName(String fullname){
    String resultFullname="";

    String[] splitted=fullname.split(" ");
    for(int i=0;i<splitted.length;i++) {
        if (!splitted[i].isEmpty()) {
            resultFullname += splitted[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + splitted[i].substring(1).toLowerCase()+" ";
        }
    }
    return resultFullname.trim();
}
```

The example input is : "JeSSe PinkMaN" and the output is "Jesse Pinkman"

Appropriate methods are : [`subString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) and [`toUpperCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase())